# Android: AutoCompleteTextView - how to customize sort order

Tags: android

The normal way how `AutoCompleteTextView` shows suggestions, is that it shows only strings that begin with the text the user entered, but the sort order of the results is undefined.

Can I somehow sort them by myself?

So that when user enters e.g. "g", I show him results beginning with "g" that are most relevant for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that if you implement a custom `Filter` and return it as part of your `ListAdapter & Filterable` implementation that you hand to the `AutoCompleteTextView`, that you can achieve your goal that way, but I have not tried this.